# Remove Particular data from JSON Array

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a Json having few data with ID null, what i want is to remove the items having id null. Please suggest the best approach.
so in itemProperty i want to remove two items where id is null

```
{ 
itemProperties :
 { 
   itemProperty: [
   {
    id:"23", 
    name: "asd"
   },
   {
    id:"232", 
    name: "asd1"
   },
   {
    id:null, 
    name: "asd2"
   },
   {
    id:"2932", 
    name: "asd3"
   },
   {
    id:null, 
    name: "asd4"
   }

 ]} }
```

Comment: You should always include your implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `.filter` method on a js array as shown below.

```
itemProperty.filter((item) => item.id !== null)
```

this will return the filtered array with only the items that pass the test.

Comment: Here is data in the scaffold in the object!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```js
var json_data = {
  "itemProperties": {
    "itemProperty": [
      {
        "id": "23",
        "name": "asd"
      },
      {
        "id": "232",
        "name": "asd1"
      },
      {
        "id": null, 
        "name": "asd2"
      },
      {
        "id": "2932",
        "name": "asd3"
      },
      {
        "id": null,
        "name": "asd4"
      }
    ]
  }
};

console.log(json_data.itemProperties.itemProperty.filter((item) => item.id !== null));
```

**O/P :**

```
[
 {
  id: "23",
  name: "asd"
 }, {
  id: "232",
  name: "asd1"
 }, {
  id: "2932",
  name: "asd3"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const jsonObj = { 
  itemProperties : { 
   itemProperty: [
     {
      id:"23", 
      name: "asd"
     },
     {
      id:"232", 
      name: "asd1"
     },
     {
      id:null, 
      name: "asd2"
     },
     {
      id:"2932", 
      name: "asd3"
     },
     {
      id:null, 
      name: "asd4"
     }
    ]
  }
}

const validItemProperty = 
  [...jsonObj.itemProperties.itemProperty].filter(i => i.id !== null )
const newJsonObj = {
  itemProperties: {
    itemProperty: validItemProperty
  }
}

console.log(newJsonObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is data in the scaffold in the object! But I update the data format

```js
const itemProperty = [{
    id: "23",
    name: "asd"
  },
  {
    id: "232",
    name: "asd1"
  },
  {
    id: null,
    name: "asd2"
  },
  {
    id: "2932",
    name: "asd3"
  },
  {
    id: null,
    name: "asd4"
  }
];

// Option One
// const data = itemProperty.filter((item) => item.id !== null);
// console.table(data)

// Option Two
function getData(data) {
  return data
    .filter((el) => el.id == null)
    .map(({
      id,
      name
    }) => ({
      id,
      name
    }));
}

console.table(getData(itemProperty));
```